# google DFP - Rotate creative from different campaign in the same AD slot

Tags: ads, google-dfp

I'm pretty new to DFP and I'm stucked with this.

I have to different campaigns (called Order in DFP), in both campaign I have one Line Item inside. Both Line Item have one creative inside. How can I rotate this two creative? Is this possible?

Can anybody also suggest me some tutorial/books that can I read to understand how DFP works?
For now I've found this one: http://www.dfptutorial.com/ but it seems to be really AdSense oriented...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the settings tab / Add targeting / Inventory section of each line item you should target the same ad unit and it should work.

You might have to make sure that they are the same type - Network would override House ads for example.

The [Google DFP documentation](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/) is quite good... it should answer most of your questions.